# Problems matching multiline separator with C++ 2011 regex (EMCAScript)

Tags: c++, regex

I'm trying to make a regular expression (for use with C++ 2011 `std::regex`, EMCAScript mode) to parse this content:

```
1
Second Line of Data for this entry
Here is the content

2
Second Line of Data for this entry
Here is the content that can be multiline
It is multiline for entry two

3 
Second Line of Data for this entry
More content
```

Notice the '2' entry here - it has content with a carriage return (\n) to the next line, but the double `\n\n` separating it from the next entry.

I've tried this regex:

```
(\\d)\n(.*)\n(.*)\n\n
```

But it doesn't do what I would expect using clang 3.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notes

- Your example data seems to have a `white-space` after the number `3`
- It's not clear if you need CRLF or just LF for line feeds.
- Be careful about the characters after the last entry any extra whitespace could cause the regex to fail to match the last item.
- You have to be careful of what `.` (dot) matches, in this case we use `[\s\S]` to get around not matching newlines.

A RegEx that will deal with the extra white-space and line feeds is as follows:

- RegEx `(\d+)\s*\r?\n(.*?)\r?\n([\s\S]*?)(?:\r?\n\r?\n|$)`
- Escaped `"(\\d+)\\s*\\r?\\n(.*?)\\r?\\n([\\s\\S]*?)(?:\\r?\\n\\r?\\n|$)"`
  [image: Regular expression visualization]

If you know you will always have an input with LF line endings it's a little more simple:

- RegEx `(\d+)\s*\n(.*?)\n([\s\S]*?)(?:\n\n|$)`
- Escaped `(\\d+)\\s*\\n(.*?)\\n([\\s\\S]*?)(?:\\n\\n|$)`
  [image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Fixed for EMCAScript mode and dot matching